# OpenCv: Get over lightness affect on the color histogram

Tags: opencv, histogram

I'm using OpenCv. For the purpose of comparison, I have to fetch data about the color histogram of an image.

In detail, I have a large amount of images which I organize into many sub sets, each sub sets consists of a group of similar images. My destination is to be able to get a new image and determine the sub set it belongs to, based on color similarity.

Now, I know how to build the histogram of an image, but my problem is how to decrease as much as possible the affect of the image's lightness on the color histogram. I have thought about using cvEqualizeHist() before calculating the histogram, but since I'm pretty new in OpenCv I'm not sure what the best way is.

Any advise is very appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

Transform your image from RGB to HSV color space using [`cvtColor()`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?#cvtcolor) with `CV_BGR2HSV` or `CV_RGB2HSV` option. H, S and V stands for Hue, Saturation and Intensity respectively. Use color histograms in this HSV space and use only a couple of bins for V channel.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I understood your meaning. Do you mean that the H and S values are not affected by the lightness? I've tried the H value and it seems that it becomes quite different under different brightness conditions. I'll be grateful if you can add an explanation

Comment: V channel carries most of the information about *lightness*; H and V channels are affected, but not as much as V. I want to remind you, there is no way that you can make a method that works 100%, at least in near future. People are researching and coming up with new ideas to solve those kind of problems.

Comment: Many thanks. Which one of H, S would you advice me to give the most weight? Do you think cvEqualizeHist() might help me? What dis you mean by "use only a couple of bins for V channel", how can I do it? Sorry for the myriad questions

Comment: First of all, I suggest you to use C++ API of OpenCV, when there is a `cv` prefix in front of a function, avoid using it, it belongs to C API which makes things hard. `equalizeHist()` may help, the only way to tell is to run some experiments using cross validation.